# Selenium Webdriver is not able to locate the third browser popup window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a link in a popup window. This the third window which is opened on clicking on a link. I tried with getWindowHandles function but webdriver is not able to get the third window.

It prints the id of two windows but when the third window gets open it is not able to locate it. Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

```html
<body onunload="MyAction('Details')">
<div class="whiteDiv">
<form name="ModalForm">
<div class="title" width="98%">What would you like to do next?</div>
<div style="padding:0 20px 20px 20px;line-height:1.5em">
<img width="16" height="16" align="absmiddle" alt="View Details " src="/common/v1/images/icons/folder.png">
<a class="linkAction" onclick="MyAction('Details'); return false;" href="#">View Details</a>
<br>
<img width="16" height="16" align="absmiddle" alt="Schedule Next Action" src="/common/v1/images/icons/action_new.png">
<a class="linkAction" onclick="MyAction('NextAction'); return false;" href="#">Schedule Next Action</a>
<br>
<img width="17" height="16" align="absmiddle" alt="Send an email" src="/common/v1/images/icons/email_send.png">
<a class="linkAction" onclick="MyAction('Email'); return false;" href="#">Send an email</a>
<br>
<img width="16" height="16" align="absmiddle" alt="Write A letter" src="/common/v1/images/icons/letter_send.png">
<a class="linkAction" onclick="MyAction('Letter'); return false;" href="#">Write a letter</a>
<br>
<img width="16" height="16" align="absmiddle" alt="Make a phone call" src="/common/v1/images/icons/phone_out.png">
<a class="linkAction" onclick="MyAction('Phone'); return false;" href="#">Make a phone call</a>
<br>
<img width="16" height="16" align="absmiddle" alt="Add a meeting note" src="/common/v1/images/icons/note_new.png">
<a class="linkAction" onclick="MyAction('Note'); return false;" href="#">Add a meeting note</a>
<br>
<img width="16" height="16" align="absmiddle" alt="Schedule Next Action" src="/common/v1/images/icons/action_new.png">
<a class="linkAction" onclick="MyAction('Close'); return false;" href="#">Close details window</a>
</div>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
</div>
</body>
```

```
driver.switchTo().window(window2);        
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Call")).click();    
System.out.println("\nClicked on Call link");    
Thread.sleep(3000);     
driver.findElement(By.id("saveRecord")).click(); // It stucks on this line although it clicked on the link

System.out.println("\nClicking on Save Record link");    
driver.switchTo().activeElement();    
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.linkText("View Details")).isDisplayed());    
driver.findElement(By.linkText("View Details")).click();
```

Comment: it may not be a new window..did you tried inspecting element in that popup and verified is it really new browser/wiindow? in my experience, i faced some iframes displaying like this..just like new popup window..

Comment: @murali seleniumtrainer- Ide is able to find the element. But while recording with ide it shows  [selectWindow | null | ] command. See the post for html code of the window.

Comment: thanks for HTML code of popup can you help me with HTML code of the parent window element from which this popup came.. simply HTML code of the element where you are clicking to get this popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Actions` and see if it able to click successfully:

```
Actions actionbuilder = new Actions(driver);
actionbuilder .moveToElement(webelement).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Yes, It worked, Now it is failing on driver.switchTo().activeElement();   Error: driver.switchTo().activeElement();

Comment: then try using the initial approach of  windowHandle. If all is set then please mark this as answer.

Comment: Any luck with solution??

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try using `driver.switchTo().activeElement();` and check if that helps. 
 Do let us know if that helps you out.

Comment: @Abhinav- The thing I monitored is that, when I clicked on the link on the 2nd window after which the 3rd popup comes, the code gets stuck on the second window. i.e link which clicked on 2nd window, it remains on 2nd window at click command.

Comment: you are not able to switch to popup window using windowHandle or switch().activeElement() ?? Also, can you post your code snippet of Selenium.

Comment: driver.switchTo().window(window2);
    
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Call")).click();

System.out.println("\nClicked on Call link");

Thread.sleep(3000);
 
driver.findElement(By.id("saveRecord")).click(); // It stucks on this line although it clicked on the link

System.out.println("\nClicking on Save Record link");

driver.switchTo().activeElement();

Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.linkText("View Details")).isDisplayed());

driver.findElement(By.linkText("View Details")).click();

Comment: Edit the post with your code, its difficult to read in code here in comment.

Comment: Is it able to find element using "driver.findElement(By.id("saveRecord")"

Comment: Yes, it is able to find the button and clicked on it, Clicking on it opens the 3rd window. But code stucks on it. No error display in console nor any failure. I have just written a print command after it, but it is not printing that.

Comment: Can you try using wait till element becomes clickable and then click on it.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(yourWebDriver, 5);    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//xpath_to_element")));

Comment: @Abhinav- Nope, it stucks on it.